# Spivak Calculus Chapter 4, Appendix 3. Polar Coordinates (Comprehension Question)

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

This appendix is for the most part very straightforward. Nevertheless, there exists one sentence that really confuses me (marked bold in the quotation).

Spivak Calculus, page 84:

> ...In many situations it is more convenient to introduce polar coordinates, which are illustrated in Figure 1. [image]
>
> To the point $P$ we assign the polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$, where $r$ is the distance from the origin $O$ to $P$, and $\theta$ is the angle between the horizontal axis and the line from $O$ to $P$. This angle can be measured either in degrees or in radians (Chapter 15), but in either case $\theta$ is not determined unambiguously. For example, with degree measurement, points on the right side of the horizontal axis could have either $\theta=0$ or $\theta=360$; moreover $\theta$ is completely ambiguous at the origin $O$. **So it is necessary to exclude some ray through the origin if we want to assign a unique pair $(r,\theta)$ to each point under consideration.**

What is the meaning of the marked sentence? What ray is he talking about?

I think this is supposed to be an example of one ray (that contains all points on the right side of the horizontal axis and the origin) which cannot have a unique pair $(r,\theta)$ assigned to any of its points. And by rotating this ray it follows that no point in the plane can have a unique pair $(r,\theta)$ assigned to it, but isn't this already obvious at this point? I'm not so sure...

Comment: I think he meant "rays" not "ray".

Comment: I think he is being a little terse. If we just eliminate the origin we can find an invertible mapping between $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}$ and $(0,\infty) \times [0, 2 \pi)$. However, this mapping is not continuous, but this can be repaired for example by restricting the mapping to between $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus ((0,\infty) \times \{0\})$ and $(0,\infty) \times (0, 2 \pi)$. (This is the opposite of the usual ray.) There is nothing special about the particular ray $((0,\infty) \times \{0\})$.)

Comment: Thank you very much! Unfortunately I'm still lost. How do we know that this mapping is not continuous? (Maybe I will have to come back to this problem after learning more about continuity. At this point I only have a vague idea of this concept.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think this is supposed to be an example of one ray (that contains all points on the right side of the horizontal axis and the origin) which cannot have a unique pair (,) assigned to any of its points.

Yes, I think this is what he means. I was confused by this paragraph as well.

He doesn't really say it, but of course our choice of $\theta$ is somewhat arbitrary, so long as it covers the full 360°-$2\pi$ radians.

We can use $\theta$'s defined by
$$0 \leq \theta \leq 360$$
or
$$73 \leq \theta \leq 433$$
or
$$-\frac{3\pi}{4} \leq \theta \leq \frac{5\pi}{4}$$

(Analogously, we could choose any ray through the origin against which we measure $\theta$. The choice to use the positive $x$-axis is somewhat arbitrary.)

In general we can use
$$\theta_0 \leq \theta \leq\theta_0 + 360$$

where $\theta_0$ is any initial angle.

I *think* what he's getting at with his "exclude some ray through the origin"
is that we exclude all points along the ray defined by $(r,\theta_0)$ where $r \geq 0$.

For any choice of $\theta_0$, we exclude the points $(r,\theta_0)$, along with the origin, leaving us only with points that can be unambiguously assigned to unique $(r, \theta)$, where $\theta_0 < \theta < \theta_0 +360$ and $r > 0$.

Analogously, We can chose to measure our $\theta$ against the positive $y$-axis, or the ray that's 76° counterclockwise from the negative $x$-axis, or any other ray through the origin, but **regardless of which one we chose we must exclude points along this ray including the origin if we want to be able to assign unique $(r, \theta)$ coordinates.**

This of course is not really satisfactory and will leave us with points we can't describe regardless of our choice of $\theta_0$

We could instead, restrict our $\theta$ to either

$$\theta_0 < \theta \leq \theta_0 + 360$$

or

$$\theta_0 \leq \theta < \theta_0 + 360$$

and define the origin point as having some fixed $\theta$, for example $\theta_0$ or $\theta_0 + 360$, depending on our choice of allowed $\theta$. **We can easily avoid the ambiguity Spivak's worried about, without excluding any rays through the origin.**

Fortunately, it's not really important. He goes on to say that, despite any difficulties in picking points on the plane and then assigning to them unique $(r, \theta)$ coordinates, going the other way is no problem at all.

Given any $(r, \theta)$, this maps to a unique $(x,y)$ in the plane, and the rest of the chapter involves this process.

Answer (score 0):

For the transformation to be univocal, you must decide if the points on axis $x$ (non-negative side) have $\theta=0$ or $2\pi$ radians.